# Not able to access variable value in PHP

Tags: php, html, mysql

This is my code to print Questions and then their respective Answers.

```
<?php 
  $reg = $_SESSION['reg'];
  $sql1="select users.reg,questions.question,questions.id from users,questions where users.reg=questions.reg and questions.company='infosys' and questions.reg!='$reg' limit 0,5";
  $query1=mysqli_query($conn,$sql1);
  $sql2="select questions.id,answers.reg,answers.answer from questions,answers where questions.id=answers.id";
  $query2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
  while($row1 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query1)){
    echo "<p class='fill'><bold>".$row1["reg"]."</bold> asked:-" ;
    echo '<br>QID:-'.$row1['id'].'&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row1["question"].'"<br></p>';
        while($row2 = mysqli_fetch_assoc($query2)){
        echo "<pre align='right'><bold>".$row2["reg"]."</bold> answered:-" ;
        echo '<br>&emsp;&emsp;"'.$row2["answer"].'"</pre>'; 
        }
echo '<form method="post" style="display:none;">';
echo '<textarea rows="2" cols="80" name="ans" class="form-control" required></textarea>';
echo '<button class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-medium w3-medium w3-margin-top w3-right" type="submit" name="answer">submit</button></form>';
echo '<button class="w3-button w3-blue w3-padding-small w3-small w3-right w3-margin-top show_button2">Answer</button><br><br>';
}
?>
```

But I'm not able to get correct output and plus I cant get the answer from the text area and insert into table with correct question ID. My INSERT code is:

```
if(isset($_POST['answer'])){
  $id = $_SESSION['id'];
  $reg = $_SESSION['reg'];
  $answer = $_POST['ans'];
  $sql="insert into answers VALUES('$id','$reg','$answer')";
  $query=mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  if($query==TRUE){
      header("location: infosys.php");
  }
}
```

Please tell me how can i access the $row variable from that scope this insert scope

Answer (score 1):

I got the solution. I stored the $row1['id'] in $id and stored that in "Submit" button's value

```
$id=$row31['id'];
echo '<form method="post" style="display:none;">';
echo '<textarea rows="2" cols="80" name="ans" class="form-control" required></textarea>';
echo '<button type="submit" name="answer_BTN" value='.$id.'">submit</button></form>';
```

and then i accessed the value via $_POST['answer_BTN'].

```
if(isset($_POST['answer_BTN'])){
  $id = $_POST['answer_BTN'];
  $reg = $_SESSION['reg'];
  $answer = $_POST['ans'];
  $sql2="insert into answers VALUES('$id','$reg','$answer')";
  $query2=mysqli_query($conn,$sql2);
  if($query2==TRUE){
      header("location: infosys.php");
  echo "<script>alert('Added your Answer!')</script>";
  }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

are you checking for submit on the same PHP File or another one?

if its another file mention the location here:

```
echo '<form method="post" action="../location/to/yourfile.php" style="display:none;">';
```

else make sure you are checking `isset()` at the top of the page

Comment: Yes I'm submitting on the same file and also i've written 'isset()' function as you can see below. @ashish